# C# SMTP email program is not using FROM address correctly

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I wrote a simple application for windows to send some emails to members of my mailing list.

The program uses my gmail account to send via SMTP. I do not want my customers having that account however,  I want them to see instead the corporate email.

I sent myself some emails to test, but the emails I am recieving are showing sent from the email account Ive logged in with at google. Any ideas?

The mail function:

```
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        //smtp host and port for gmail
        string host = txtHost.Text;
        int port;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(txtPort.Text, out port))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid port number.");
            return;
        }          

        //compose email
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Sender = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text, txtFrom.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text, txtFrom.Text);

        msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);

        msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        msg.Body = rTxtMessage.Text;

        msg.IsBodyHtml = chkHtml.Checked;


        //msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text, txtFrom.Text);

        //create smtp client
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port);

        //TODO: Move constants to the NetworkCredentials call
        string username = SMTP_USERNAME;
        string password = SMTP_PASSWORD;

        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            //Send email
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            //Log if any errors occur
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the application and result screenshots: 
[image: Application running]
[image: What came to my inbox]

Answer (score 0):

You should set:

```
msg.Sender
```

to your Company address.

Comment: msg.Sender = txtFrom.Text;

Comment: I've made that change, still does not work. I will change the question to include the updated code block and add images of the result and application

Comment: It's Google that is replacing the address you entered with the address of the account logged in. That's a feature, not a bug. Or would you like it, if everyone could send Emails and use your address as a sender?